# zx01 file saved as zip when downloaded

Tags: sharepoint, file-extension, winzip

I have SharePoint document library that contains a .zx01. The problem occurs when I try to download that file -- instead of getting a .zx01 file, I am receiving a .zip file.

Is this normal WinZip behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it's IE that's changing the file extension for "security measures" against malicious files. The file was downloaded fine in Chrome.